# 5e D&D Monk/Warlock Build Help

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, monk, warlock

So I will be playing a 5e D&D campaign soonish for the first time, and have very little experience with D&D so I would like some help with my character build. I am really liking the idea of a Way of Shadow Monk with a dip in Warlock for Devil's Sight and was probably going to go Elf, I envision him as a magical spy/assassin outside of combat and battlefield control in combat and was going to go Charlatan for his background.

What I need help with is how many levels in warlock I should take and what Patron/Pack Boon/Invocations/etc I should take. I was thinking of going with the Fey for their extra spells/control abilities and was tossing up between Pact of the Chain for the early/better familiar so I can cast Darkness on something and have it move the Darkness where I need it, and Pact of the Tome for the extra cantrips and maybe the Book of Ancient Secrets Invocation.

So what do you all think/what advice do you have?

Comment: Added [tag:optimization] and [tag:dnd-5e]. The others might want you to add more criteria, else your question will be put on hold for it being too broad. Try thinking about what exactly you want your character to be able to do. *(For instance, max DPR.)* Welcome to the site!

Comment: You may also want to add at what level your character will be made at, and how long you expect that character to be around. Plans to get to lvl 20 are great, but I'm not sure many people actually get up there.

Comment: We also need to know what your optimisation goal is before we can help with optimisation questions. It's well and good to ask for "what you all think is best" on a discussion forum, but in our Q&A site format we need more detail because we can't have back-and-forth discussion here when an answer makes a mistaken assumption about your question. We need enough information in the question that an expert can answer it without asking you for more information first.